# Voice state update event

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to move the bot from 1 channel to another when the user switches channels

```js
const client = require("../index.js");
module.exports = client => {
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
  let oldChannel = oldState.voiceChannel, // the previous channel, if there was one
    newChannel = newState.voiceChannel; // the current channel, if there is one

  if (oldChannel != newChannel) {
    // if the channel has changed
    // do your stuff....
    channel = msg.member.voice.channel
channel.join()
  }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `newState`'s `voiceChannel`

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
  let oldChannel = oldState.voiceChannel, // the previous channel, if there was one
  let newChannel = newState.voiceChannel; // the current channel, if there is one

  if (oldChannel != newChannel) {
      newChannel.join();
  }
});
```